# How to determine which element getting focus in ie 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, events

I want to focusout event in (Chrome, Ie 6-10) or in blur event in Firefox know which elements is going to get focus. 
In the chrome and IE before 11 it is possible using below code:

```
$(input).focusout(function (event) {
            "use strict";
            console.log("next focused element: ", event.relatedTarget);
        });
```

In Firefox it is possible using the below code:

```
$(input).blur(function (event) {
            "use strict";
             console.log("next focused element:",  event.originalEvent.explicitOriginalTarget);
            });
```

The problem is IE 11. I can not find any way to do that in IE 11. Somebody who has found a solution for this?

Here is fiddle for testing with ie11.
http://jsfiddle.net/govanm/y87sekzd/5/

Comment: `event.relatedTarget` is working fine on IE11: http://jsfiddle.net/twd491pp/1/

Comment: Strange. @AlvaroMontoro Your fiddle is working apparently. But I am sure there is bug. Look at this: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/814285/focus-and-blur-events-should-have-relatedtarget

Comment: I tested you fiddle now. If you remove id attribute from your inputs. You are going to get the null. My problem is that I can not put id attribute for whole the page. We are using some frames that the code has been written by another company and they don't have id attribute. @AlvaroMontoro

Comment: If you remove the id attribute, you have to change the JSFiddle code from `event.relatedTarget.id` (that will be null as there is no id anymore) to just `event.relatedTarget`. Then you'll see that IE11 is returning the `object HTMLInputElement` correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/twd491pp/4/

Comment: Now I created a fiddle based on my code. Please try that one. http://jsfiddle.net/govanm/y87sekzd/5/    @AlvaroMontoro

Comment: I am able to see the bug now, and I think I came up with a workaround for IE11, let me post it as an answer as it's a bit long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could see the issue on the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/govanm/y87sekzd/5/) that you shared in the comments, and I was able to come up with a workaround solution.

The idea of this workaround is that before the `focusout` happens, some select/focus event triggers in the target element. So we can keep track of that by using some auxiliary variable:

```
var nextElement = null;

$("input").on("select click mousedown pointerdown mspointerdown", function() {
    nextElement = this;
});
```

I used different events that will be triggered when an element is selected (using the mouse or the keyboard) and that happen before the `focusout` event.

Now that we have the `nextElement`, on the `focusout` event of the current element, we'll check the value of `event.relatedTarget`. If it's not null (all but IE11), we'll use it; if it's null (IE11), we'll use the `nextElement` variable instead:

```
var nextFocus =  event.relatedTarget ? event.relatedTarget : nextElement;

$("#p1").append("<div>next focused element: " + nextFocus.id + "</div>");
```

That way we won't affect the behavior on the other browsers, and it will work once IE11 fixes the [know bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/814285/focus-and-blur-events-should-have-relatedtarget) that you shared in the comments.

The whole code would look like this:

```js
var nextElement = null;

$("input").on("select click mousedown pointerdown mspointerdown", function() {
  nextElement = this;
});

$("input").focusout(function (event) {

  "use strict";

  var nextFocus =  event.relatedTarget ? event.relatedTarget : nextElement;

  $("#p1").append("<div>next focused element: " + nextFocus.id + "</div>");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="group">
    <tbody>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="field_title">
            <div class="widget_title widget_committed"><span id="sales_responsbile_part_last_name_field-title">* Last name:</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="field_widget">
            <div class="configurationWidget_configuration-custom-text-widget_0">
                <div class="widget_input"><input type="text" name="sales_responsbile_part_last_name_field" value="gf" id="in1">
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="field_filler"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="field_title">
            <div class="widget_title widget_committed"><span id="sales_responsbile_part_first_name_field-title">* First name:</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="field_widget">
            <div class="configurationWidget_configuration-custom-text-widget_0">
                <div class="widget_input"><input type="text" name="sales_responsbile_part_first_name_field" value="hj" id="in2">
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="field_filler"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="field_title">
            <div class="widget_title widget_committed"><span id="sales_responsbile_part_title_field-title">Title:</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="field_widget">
            <div class="configurationWidget_configuration-custom-text-widget_0">
                <div class="widget_input"><input type="text" name="sales_responsbile_part_title_field" value="hj" id="in3"></div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="field_filler"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="field_title">
            <div class="widget_title widget_committed"><span
                    id="sales_responsbile_part_phone_field-title">* Phone:</span></div>
        </td>
        <td class="field_widget">
            <div class="configurationWidget_configuration-custom-text-widget_0">
                <div class="widget_input"><input type="text" name="sales_responsbile_part_phone_field" value="jhjh" id="in4">
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="field_filler"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="field_title">
            <div class="widget_title widget_committed"><span
                    id="sales_responsbile_part_mobile_field-title">Alt. phone:</span></div>
        </td>
        <td class="field_widget">
            <div class="configurationWidget_configuration-custom-text-widget_0">
                <div class="widget_input"><input type="text" name="sales_responsbile_part_mobile_field" value="hjh" id="in5">
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="field_filler"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="field_title">
            <div class="widget_title widget_committed"><span
                    id="sales_responsbile_part_email_field-title">* E-mail:</span></div>
        </td>
        <td class="field_widget">
            <div class="configurationWidget_configuration-custom-text-widget_0">
                <div class="widget_input"><input type="text" name="sales_responsbile_part_email_field" value="hjh" id="in6">
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="field_filler"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="field_title">
            <div class="widget_title widget_committed"><span id="sales_responsbile_part_sales_channel_field-title">Sales channel:</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="field_widget">
            <div class="configurationWidget_configuration-custom-text-widget_0">
                <div class="widget_input"><input type="text" name="sales_responsbile_part_sales_channel_field"
                                                 value="hjh" id="in7"></div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="field_filler"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="field_title">
            <div class="widget_title widget_committed"><span
                    id="sales_responsbile_part_sales_responsbile_segment_field-title">Sales responsible segment:</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="field_widget">
            <div class="configurationWidget_configuration-custom-text-widget_0">
                <div class="widget_input"><input type="text"
                                                 name="sales_responsbile_part_sales_responsbile_segment_field"
                                                 value="jhjh" id="in8"></div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="field_filler"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="field_title">
            <div class="widget_title widget_committed"><span id="sales_responsbile_part_sales_team_field-title">Sales team:</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="field_widget">
            <div class="configurationWidget_configuration-custom-text-widget_0">
                <div class="widget_input"><input type="text" name="sales_responsbile_part_sales_team_field" value="hjh" id="in9">
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="field_filler"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
 <p id="p1">Test</p>
```

And you can see it on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y87sekzd/7/

Comment: Thanks for workaround. I accepted that as answer. How ever I like to know the focus for all html elements and not just for  inputs. For examples links, textarea and so on. Is there a way to generalize this for all elements?

Comment: Instead of doing `$("input")`, you could do `$("*")` to apply it to all the elements